# Truffle error: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I am using truffle:

```
truffle(development)> var hw  
undefined 
truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(deployed){hw=deployed;}); 
undefined 
truffle(development)> hw.SayHello.call()
```

i am getting below error in Truffle

```
***Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert 
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:41484:16) 
    at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:328866:36 
    at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:324536:9 
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:327565:7) 
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176407:18)  
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176697:12) 
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176852:12) 
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176812:24) 
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20) 
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7) ***
```

**1) My HelloWorld.sol** 

`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
contract HelloWorld { 
   function SayHello() public returns (string) { 
        return ("SomeHello"); 
    } 
}
```

**2) My 2_deploy_contracts.js**

```
var ConvertLib = artifacts.require("./ConvertLib.sol");
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");
var second = artifacts.require("./second.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) { 
  deployer.deploy(ConvertLib);
  deployer.link(ConvertLib, MetaCoin); 
  deployer.deploy(MetaCoin); 
  deployer.deploy(HelloWorld);
  deployer.deploy(second);
};
```

**3) My truffle.js**

```
module.exports = { 
  networks: { 
    development: { 
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8545, 
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id 
    } 
  } 
};
```

Please let me know how can I fix above error ?

`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your example and it worked fine. The only change I made was I removed the other smart contracts from 2_deploy_contracts that aren't used. Make sure you are running the `compile` and `migrate` commands and `testrpc` is running before starting the truffle console. Also, just in case you're running on Windows, rename `truffle.js` to `truffle-config.js`

```
$ truffle compile 
Compiling .\contracts\HelloWorld.sol... 
Writing artifacts to .\build\contracts

$ truffle migrate 
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js   
Deploying HelloWorld...   
... 0xef7e895758805a3c3c9aaed7dc7c97fe7b2278b0c0d6ee8105192183a86188c9 
HelloWorld: 0x54329ff919efda7920408084590d7480a6c88243 
Saving successful migration to network...   
... 0x0954625bf66275469c9475ca21f5db20bc4667efb716c5e19bfd98a9553f4a83 
Saving artifacts...

$ truffle console 
truffle(development)> var hw 
undefined 
truffle(development)> HelloWorld.deployed().then(function(deployed){hw=deployed;}); 
undefined 
truffle(development)> hw.SayHello.call() 
'SomeHello' 
truffle(development)>
```

2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require("./HelloWorld.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {   deployer.deploy(HelloWorld); };
```